# Is there an OSX shortcut to highlight the cursor position?

Tags: macos, accessibility, cursor

I have recently moved from Windows to OSX. I work with multiple screens, so was used to losing the cursor on occasion.

There was a setting in Windows to highlight the cursor location by pressing `Ctrl`. Is there a similar setting in OSX?